# Jhipster startup failed with "Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I had installed JHipster and configured in MyEclipse. Once I started running main class for *App.java I got error...here is the output from console. Please help me figure out as I am trying to find out solution to this since last couple of days...

```
 --------------------
    Running with Spring Boot v1.5.9.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.13.RELEASE

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at com.io.is.IntellisummaryApp.main(IntellisummaryApp.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:125)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:152)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:124)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:238)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:57)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1232)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:156)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:130)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:76)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:58)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.apply(ZkUtils.scala)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:171)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicsIfAutoCreateEnabledAndAdminUtilsPresent(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:153)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:110)
    ... 23 common frames omitted`df
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New JHipster application crashing when started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268825/new-jhipster-application-crashing-when-started)